# How to know active network of Wifi or Wlan

Tags: iphone

I want to know active available network name and its network type like if I have 5 wifi available then it should display all 5 wifi name and type of network is WIFI.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the iOS SDK, you can only detect the netwerk type (wan, WiFi, etc) and since iOS 7 the WAN connection type (LTE, 3G, Edge, etc).

You can use the [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) code from Apple to detect the current connection type and monitor changes.